# How to clone a Generator?

Tags: rust, generator

Is it possible to clone a variable of type `std::ops::Generator`? There is a generator, I want to create a new instance, with a clean stack, there is no `clone()` method. I tried inside `Box` and inside `Pin`, but it does not clone!

```rust
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]

fn main() {
    let gen = move || yield ();

    let gen1 = gen.clone();

    let gen = Box::new(move || yield ());
    let gen1 = gen.clone();

    let gen = Box::pin(move || yield ());
    let gen1 = gen.clone();
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `clone` found for type `[generator@src/main.rs:4:15: 4:31 _]` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:20
  |
6 |     let gen1 = gen.clone();
  |                    ^^^^^
```

As I understand it, closures can be cloned; what is wrong with generators?

The only workaround I've found is to return the generator from some function (then it will be new every time), but this is syntactically inconvenient for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is [not possible to clone a generator](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57972).

The current workaround is to construct a new generator every time you need to reset it.

> a variable of type `std::ops::Generator`

These are not variables of that type any more than `|| foo()` is a variable of type `Fn()`. `Generator` is a *trait* and `dyn Generator` is a *type*. Your `gen` variables are anonymous types that *implement* the trait `Generator`.

See also:

- [What does "dyn" mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/155423)
- [Is there any way to explicitly write the type of a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29191170/155423)